# How can I set a highlighted image on a table view cell?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, uitableview

I've followed the code in Apple's [AdvancedTableViewCells](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/index.html) and built a table view with a background image for cells. Now I want to change it so that instead of the blue highlight colour, it shows a darker version of my image. What are the steps I need to follow to do this? I'm using a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a custom NIB. My background image is implemented as the `cell.backgroundView`.

The steps I've take so far are:

- Change the `selectionStyle` of the cell to "None"
- Set the Highlight colour on my `UILabel` subviews to a light colour
- Create a darker version of my background as a separate image
- Override `setSelected: animated:`

I'm wondering about the next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace the image inside `setSelected: animated:`?

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (selected) {
        // replace image here
        // or move a pointer from one image to another
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was trying, but I have to deal with deselection manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `selectedBackgroundView` property. I'm using this approach instead of `setSelected: animated:`

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    NSString *backgroundImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TableBackground" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundImagePath];
    self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage] autorelease];
    self.backgroundView.frame = self.bounds;

    NSString *selectedBackgroundImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TableBackgroundDark" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *selectedBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:selectedBackgroundImagePath];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectedBackgroundImage] autorelease];
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = self.bounds;

    return self;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way, as it's introduced a couple of other problems. One thing is that the cell `selectionStyle` has to be something other than `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` or it won't show the background image. The deselection animation has stopped working too. I'll open a new question about these problems.